# Jest uncovered lines from the start of the file

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, code-coverage

Jest coverage report in console shows uncovered lines from the end of the file, which is a bit annoying as usually it makes sense to write tests from the beginning of the file.

I can't seem to find any documentation. Obviously I could look at full coverage reports, but that's not that convenient.

Ideally developer would like to see uncovered lines from file beginning.

Comment: `man head` may help

Comment: I think the problem is jest configuration itself, be it configurable or hardcoded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's hardcoded in Istanbul, which Jest is using for coverage so there's not much we can do besides modifying it's code in `node_modules`.

One workaround for this that I'm using: **temporary** use Istanbul ignore comments to scale down coverage report of that file
`/* istanbul ignore next */` below the function that you are testing.